# (Xcode) Links Between UIButtons and pages

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, uibutton

Hey guys I'm a newbie developer with cocoa and I'm Trying to create a simple app. which display 4 differents pages that you can select via a tab bar.

My Problem: I made a UIButton on the First/Home page (==>FirstView.xib) with IB and i tried to link it to my second page (==>SecondView.xib) with some code found on the net.

The thing is that i can build my code but nothing happens when I try to click on my button, can you help me ?

**Code for FirstView.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

UIButton *button;}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

- (IBAction)goToViewTwo;

@end
```

**Code for FirstView.m:**
    @implementation FirstViewController
    @synthesize button;

```
- (IBAction)goToViewTwo {
SecondViewController *SecondView= [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:SecondView animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [button release];
}

@end
```

**About the outlets in FIrstVIew.xib**:

I linked "Touch Up Inside" to "goToViewTwo" and "b^utton" to "File's Owner'

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression this is in a tab bar where each tab bar button displays a .xib file.  If this is the case, the solution is fairly simple.  Your tabBarController manages your views in an array of view controllers.  To switch between them, your IBAction method should be the following:

```
- (IBAction)goToViewTwo {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

This tells your tab bar controller to switch from your current view controller (at index 0) to the second (at index 1)

Comment: Holy s*** ^^ , Thank you Very much (feel so stupid now :o) it works fine :)

Comment: My pleasure, man.  No need to feel stupid, though.  You figure out a bunch of useful stuff as the time goes by.  An accepted answer would be much appreciated, though =]